# How Can I Format My Tikz Figure Correctly?

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats

I am having problems formatting my picture correctly.  There are three graphs here.  I'd like the first two to be side by side and the third to be under them.  With what I've got the first two pictures are side by side, but the second picture is a little lower than the first.

The second issue I am having is labeling.  The labels `A_1`, `A_2`, and `A_{-\pi}` are listed on the bottom right of the graph.  I would like to adjust them to either the top left or along the bottom.  Note: I do not want "Figure 1.1" or "(a)" to appear.  I just want "A_1", etc.

The final problem is that the these figures happen to be the first thing on a new page in the document.  But, they are shifted down the page too far.  Can I place them only an inch or so from the top?  I placed the [!t] hoping that would help.  It did not.

EDIT: I have solved problem 3.  By adding more text below the pictures, TeX shifted them up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]

\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    ymin=-.3, ymax=1.3, ytick={0}, ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, xtick={-1,1}, xlabel=$x$
    ]
    \addplot[<->][domain=-1:1, red, thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
{$A_1$}\quad

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    ymin=-.2, ymax=2.3, ytick={1,2}, ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, xtick={-1,1}, xlabel=$x$
    ]
    \addplot[<->][domain=-1:1, red, thick] {(-1*x^2+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
{$A_2$}}

\subfloat{  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    ymin=-4, ymax=1.3, ytick={1,-3}, ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, xtick={-1,1}, xlabel=$x$
    ]
    \addplot[<->][domain=-1:1, red, thick] {4.14159*x^2-3.14159};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
{$A_{-\pi}$}}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use same values of `ymin=-.2, ymax=2.3,` in first and second graphs.

Comment: To move label to the top left of the graph, you can add for example `\node at(current bounding box.north west){$A_1$};` after drawing the first graph. If you don't want the labels to take up horizontal space, add option `[overlay]` to the `\node` command

Comment: @HarishKumar Your comment was very useful.

Comment: @KevinC Your comment was useful as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first problem, you can use same values of ymin=-.2, ymax=2.3, in first and second graphs.

For the second, you can put`A`'s as caption and get rid of `label`ling by  using `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = empty}` inside the `figure` environment if you want this only for one figure. Otherwise, put it in the preamble. The syntax is `\subfloat[<list entry>][<sub-caption>]{<body>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = empty}
\centering
\subfloat[$A_1$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-.2, ymax=2.3, ytick={0}, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, xtick={-1,1}, xlabel=$x$
    ]
    \addplot[<->][domain=-1:1, red, thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat[$A_2$]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-.2, ymax=2.3, ytick={1,2}, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, xtick={-1,1}, xlabel=$x$
    ]
    \addplot[<->][domain=-1:1, red, thick] {(-1*x^2+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\subfloat[$A_{-\pi}$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-4, ymax=1.3, ytick={1,-3}, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-2, xmax=2, xtick={-1,1}, xlabel=$x$
    ]
    \addplot[<->][domain=-1:1, red, thick] {4.14159*x^2-3.14159};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]